# PHP session changes unexpectedly in if statement and ignores echo command

Tags: php, session, if-statement

I'm setting $_SESSION['showroom'] to 'active' when a particular page in Wordpress is displayed:

```
if(get_the_ID()==6470||get_the_ID()==252){
    $_SESSION['showroom']='active';
}
```

I then set 2 arrays of pages to check against. If the next page displayed is NOT in one of these arrays, $_SESSION['showroom'] gets changed to 'inactive'.

```
$allowed_templates = array('template-A.php',
                           'template-B.php',
                           'template-C.php',
                           'template-E.php',
                           'template-G.php');
$allowed_ids = array(6470,252);

$template_name = get_page_template_slug();
$page_id = get_the_ID();

if(in_array($template_name,$allowed_templates)==false && in_array($page_id,$allowed_ids)==false){
    $_SESSION['showroom']='inactive';
}
```

The if statement works most of the time, but sometimes my $_SESSION['showroom'] changes to inactive EVEN though one of the arrays is returning true! After several hours of testing I am unable to locate where the problem is. Echoing out the two parts of the if statement ALWAYS gives me 2 trues or 1 true + 1 false, but never 2 falses:

```
if(in_array($template_name,$allowed_templates)==false){echo 'TFALSE';}
if(in_array($template_name,$allowed_templates)){echo 'TTRUE';}
if(in_array($page_id,$allowed_ids)==false){echo 'IFALSE';}
if(in_array($page_id,$allowed_ids)){echo 'ITRUE';}
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: Have continued testing and found the following anomaly:

```
    if(in_array($template_name,$allowed_templates)==false && in_array($page_id,$allowed_ids)==false){
    $_SESSION['showroom']='inactive';
    echo 'SET TO INACTIVE';
}
```

The if statement changes $_SESSION['showroom'] to 'inactive' but DOES NOT echo out 'SET TO INACTIVE'!

There's something strange going on here!

Comment: `if(in_array($template_name,$allowed_templates) && in_array($page_id,$allowed_ids)){
    $_SESSION['showroom']='inactive';
}` or  `if(in_array($template_name,$allowed_templates)===false && in_array($page_id,$allowed_ids)===false){
    $_SESSION['showroom']='inactive';
}`

Comment: What do you see if you put all those `if..echo` statements inside the `if` that sets the session variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem solved. My code was fine. Two missing images files were causing WordPress to crash my sessions. Took 10 hours to find out but happy I found it. Thanks to everyone for their help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following;

```
 if(!in_array($template_name,$allowed_templates) && !in_array($page_id,$allowed_ids)){
     $_SESSION['showroom']='inactive';
 }
```

Edit: lets try and break it down further... similar to your examples

```
 if(!in_array($template_name,$allowed_templates){
     echo "not in templates,";
 }
 if(!in_array($page_id,$allowed_ids)){
     echo "not in ids,";
 }
 if(!in_array($template_name,$allowed_templates) && !in_array($page_id,$allowed_ids)){
     echo "not in both\n";
 }
```

then see if we get a result with `not in templates,not in ids,` but no trailing `not in both`

Comment: Thanks Dave. !in_array was what I tried originally, but same problem. Resorted to ==false as an alternative but still no luck!

Comment: Since `in_array` returns a boolean, there's absolutely no difference between `!in_array()` and `in_array() == false`.

Comment: @Barmar - you are correct, and this is similar to Anant's comment as well.

Comment: See additional edit to see if this gives us an unexplained result.

Comment: just a quick confirmation...  you do know that `in_array()` is case-sensitive and the data you are using may or may not be failing the match as a result of that correct?  Assume you would have seen that behavior in your echo statements

Comment: @Dave - checked that as well. Everything is lowercase.

Comment: did you try and confirm the second half (everything below "Edit:") and confirm the results?

Comment: @Dave - just tested as you suggested. I added echo $_SESSION['showroom'] to get the full picture. Everything is fine except for some problem pages. Here's the ouput: not in ids,inactive. Surely this isn't possible...?

Comment: @ALL - please see edit for further strange behaviour!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is pure logical. Lets look at this statement:

```
if (in_array($template_name,$allowed_templates)==false && in_array($page_id,$allowed_ids)==false)
```

Which translates to *"If the template is not valid **AND** page is not valid"*

This means that both statements needs to be fulfilled in order to mark session as inactive. What if the template is fine, but the page is not valid? That definitely should be marked as inactive as well.

By changing the statement to read *"If the template is not valid **OR** page is not valid"*, we cover up the invalid cases. Because either of them counts as an invalid state, and thus, only one of them needs to be false in order for everything to be false. (the OR-statement)

So code-wise it would be

```
if (in_array($template_name,$allowed_templates)==false || in_array($page_id,$allowed_ids)==false)
```

And you are set.

As and addition. I would structure the code as you noted works. Which is more logical. That is, mark it as inactive whenever it's should be treated as inactive, in all other cases mark it as 'active'. Or vice-versa.

Comment: thanks, but I need to check against BOTH arrays. The session ONLY becomes inactive when the template AND the page id is invalid.